# I use itexsharp, error message :" The color space [/Separation, /Black, /DeviceCMYK, 67 0 R] is not supported.", are you solutions?

Tags: itext

The color space [/Separation, /Black, /DeviceCMYK, 67 0 R] is not supported.

Comment: Please tell us in which context that error occurs, provide some pivotal source and the stacktrace.

Comment: *My TV doesn't work, can you fix it?* That's how your question sounds. It can't be answered if you don't provide more info.

Comment: @Mkl: Error line code:  iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject pdfImage =
                                                    new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject((PRStream) pdfStrem);

Comment: Context? Stacktrace? And a single line of code obviously is hardly sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

According to a comment, the OP observed the error in this code line

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject pdfImage = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject((PRStream) pdfStrem);
```

i.e. while constructing a `iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject`. Thus, quite likely this occurred while parsing a PDF and trying to extract images from it.

The cause for the error is that this iText(Sharp) class simply cannot handle all variants in which the PDF specification allows image data to be embedded in a PDF. Especially complex color spaces (like the separation color space used in your image) usually only are used in the printing industry and cannot easily be stored in a standard image format supported by iText without loss.

As in your code you have the PDF objects at hand in which the image data is stored (the `PRStream` and objects referenced from it), you can still extract the image data and store it in a format you prefer making use of the information in the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) starting in section 8.9 *Images*.

By the way, the PDF specification requires only that *a conforming reader shall support **Separation** colour spaces with the colorant names **All** and **None***, but your color space uses the colorant name **Black** and, therefore, is not necessarily supported by PDF processors in general.